# Connect and modify SQL server from Selenium using Ruby (no Rails)

Tags: sql-server, ruby, dbi, sequel

I guess Selenium isn't that important to this question but I thought I'd add it in. Also, I'm not using Rails.

I need to access Sqlserver and delete some records using ruby. Nothing too crazy. I've found some information online but I would like to know what you recommend is the best way to do this.

I've come across the DBI and SEQUEL gems but am unsure about the amount of time I'll need to invest to get up and running. Also, are there any better alternatives?

Thank you

Comment: found an easy answer here. http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3906

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [tiny_tds](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds) to see if that fits your needs. It's pretty bare-bones without an ORM.